# One bootstrap dropdown works, and the other doesnt on the same page

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've got a navbar with two dropdown elements in it, controlled by bootstrap-ui.

The strange thing is that one is working and the other is not. This code is coming from the mean.js boilerplate, so anyone whose familiar with that will know their way around. I suspect its something to do with the order of the bootstrap javascript files. here is my order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker/datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

and here is the offending code

```
 //This guy isn't working at all!!
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="!isCollapsed" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-ng-if="menu.shouldRender(authentication.user);">
            <li data-ng-repeat="item in menu.items | orderBy: 'position'" data-ng-if="item.shouldRender(authentication.user);" ng-switch="item.menuItemType" ui-route="{{item.uiRoute}}" class="{{item.menuItemClass}}" ng-class="{active: ($uiRoute)}" dropdown="item.menuItemType === 'dropdown'">
                <a ng-switch-when="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <span data-ng-bind="item.title"></span>
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul ng-switch-when="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li data-ng-repeat="subitem in item.items | orderBy: 'position'" data-ng-if="subitem.shouldRender(authentication.user);" ui-route="{{subitem.uiRoute}}" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}">
                        <a href="/#!/{{subitem.link}}" data-ng-bind="subitem.title"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a ng-switch-default href="/#!/{{item.link}}" data-ng-bind="item.title"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

       //This guy is working no problem
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-ng-show="authentication.user">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span data-ng-bind="authentication.user.displayName"></span> <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/#!/settings/profile">Edit Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/#!/settings/accounts">Manage Social Accounts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-ng-show="authentication.user.provider === 'local'">
                        <a href="/#!/settings/password">Change Password</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/auth/signout">Signout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Does anyone have any idea whats going on here?

I'm using bootstap-ui v 0.12.1 in case that makes a difference .

Comment: Hi, in another post there was a version issue that caused a problem.  Try using version to 0.12.0. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading 'competing' libraries.  First, the Angular UI Bootstrap library is meant to replace the Bootstrap javascript implementation (see Philosophy section [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Project-Philosophy)), so remove:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Second, there are 2 Angular UI Bootstrap packages, one that includes the directive templates, and one without (details explained [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/gh-pages#build-files)), so remove:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

What is most likely occurring is that the 3 libraries all attached their own close/open handlers for the dropdown and they are fighting each other.